# Change of Variable in a Gaussian Integral

Tags: vector-spaces, gaussian-integral

Let's assume I have Euclidean vector space ${\rm R}^n$ over real numbers ${\rm R}$ with the inner product $\left< \cdot | \cdot \right>$. 
Then, for a symmetric positive definite real $n\times n$ matrix $A$, 
we have

$$ \int d^n x~ e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left< x | A | x \right> 
+ \left< J | x \right>} 
= \left( \frac{(2\pi)^n}{\det A} \right)^{1/2}
e^{\frac{1}{2} \left< J | A^{-1} | J \right> }, $$
where $x$ and $J$ are Euclidean vectors.

How to prove from above that 
$$ \int d^n x~ e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left< x | A | x \right> 
+ i \left< J | x \right>} 
= \left( \frac{(2\pi)^n}{\det A} \right)^{1/2}
e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left< J | A^{-1} | J \right> } ~~ ?$$

I guess one should not be able to use simple transformation $J \to -i J$ since 
inner product of $\left< -i J | x \right>$ is not well defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it amounts to what you said, although you still use the usual real inner product with the $i$ in there, and that gives you a factor of $-1$. To understand what's going on, you have to look at (the beginning of) the derivation of the first formula — you complete the square, substituting $x-A^{-1}J$ for $x$. Now you do the same thing with $iJ$. To finish the argument, you need to use a little bit of complex analysis to argue that the integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$ does not change if you push in the imaginary direction and consider $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty+ic}^{\infty+ic} e^{-z^2}\,dz$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the part I'm worried about is that $iJ$ is no longer a vector in Euclidean space so the inner product does not exist. But if I understand the suggestion, I don't have to do this and can again orthogonalize $A$, thus splitting the integral into $n$ independent ones, solve the 1d integrals and combine them again with finally the minus outside.

Comment: You can "complexify" the inner product (making it complex-linear in both factors, unlike the hermitian inner product). That's not an issue. But the integral will become a complex line integral and you do need Cauchy's Theorem at the end.

Comment: ok, got it. cheers!